# Visual Studio 2010 C project - Install as service

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, service, installation, setup-project

I have a program built in Visual Studio 2010. The project has an installer, which was built using the "Setup Project" template of Visual Studio. It works when I want to install my program as a program which the user calls.

However, my program needs to run as a Windows service on startup, and I can't seem to find any  guides on having the setup project do that for C++.

What steps need to be taken for a Visual Studio 2010 Setup Project to install my program as a windows service?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether it is possible with VS Setup project.
In NSIS you can use http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NSIS_Simple_Service_Plugin this plug-in.

So a quick solution for you is to create simple NSIS installer (.exe app) and lauch it from your installer.